# How to save token number which is shown in inspact/network when I hit API

Tags: laravel

[image] In my project what I want when I hit API with two parameters that is UserName and Password it generate dynamic token number for particular user that going to login .

So what i want that when user come to my login portal in backend A api Hit of a SSO system if user is register on SSO than he access my dashboard if not than he back to login page       For this when user login his API generate a token (Like: _token: RH0QaImZq8GzCSn0lk8awEmpfYamIIVShtKo5qPP) so if that token matches form my side also than after user redirect to dashboard

````
**I tried this in my Controller**:--

 ```  $UserName = $request->input('UserName');
        $Password = $request->input('Password');

        // Send a request to the SSO system to validate the credentials
        $response = Http::post('http://sso.gov.in:0000/SSOREST/SSOAuthJSON', [
            'UserName' => $UserName,
            'Password' => $Password,
        ]);
   
        // Check if the authentication was successful and retrieve the token
        if ($response->status() == 200 && isset($response['_token'])) {
            $token = $response['_token'];

            // Redirect the user to the dashboard with the token as a parameter
            return redirect('/dashboard', ['_token' => $token]);
            // return redirect()->route('dashboard', ['_token' => $token]);
        } else {
            // Authentication failed, redirect the user back to the login page with an error message
            return back()->with('fail', 'Invalid username or password.');               
        }
    ```

Please Help me how to handle this error.
````

When the user enters their username and password on my login page, my web application sends a request to the SSO system to validate those credentials. If the credentials are valid, the SSO system responds with a token that my web application can use to authenticate subsequent requests.

[image: payload]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an internal login system.

But never the less you can save your token in a db table and match it to user.

If you're not on a shared host, You can use `redis` which is faster.

### Note

You're sending `_token`. API doesn't generate this token. you're doing wrong.

SSO won't give you a token! I don't know what you want to do!
But Your `$response` is logged in to that site. If you want to simulate a proxy you should save the response `cookies` use them later again!

Comment: thank you sir I got the answer sorry i didn't reply you for two days